# Issue with creating athena tables from CSV files using glue

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I created a glue crawler to load multiple csv files of a S3 folder into 1 table on Athena and all the files are of same CSV format.
Am using crawler for that purpose using CSV classifier. But the files have columns with 'commas and double quotes' in between. Due to which the columns are not getting created properly in table as Crawler treats commas in column as separator.
But While creating table manually in Athena i was having option to give serde and give escape chars in table definition as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dump_table as (
columns
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'separatorChar'=',')  
LOCATION 's3://folder1//source' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false',
  'skip.header.line.count'='1'
);
```

Problem am facing is that am unable to give the escape character as comma in classifier for crawler and neither am able to give the serde information in crawler as how i gave while creating manual table.
Could anyone please help me with loading this CSV data into table which has columns with 'commas in between a column'

Comment: Please Edit your question to provide a small sample of the input file (you can use fake data) that exhibits the problem with the crawler.

Comment: Hi John, l have a column like description with values as below:

Comment: Hi John, l have a columns like fullname, job description and address with values as commas in between: example "Rajan, Kooram" as value in name column and "london, uk" as address column and "working in Infosys, London,UK" as description. I need to load these sort of columns from CSV into Athena declaring the 'comma and double quotes as escape characters". I tried using classifier but there is no option for "special chars" in classifiers. Please suggest me how i can add this schema in runtime to Athena by crawlers

Comment: Please provide actual sample of lines that we can use to reproduce your situation. That is, if we use the crawler on your sample lines, it will exhibit the problems you are describing.